# Why is React rendering children?

Tags: reactjs

React should not be rendering the children of `DataView`. Why am I getting an exception here? I'm getting an exception because `data` is undefined, but it should not be hitting that part of the code because `isLoading` is still true. What am I missing?

```
import { useQuery } from "react-query"
import { loadAccounts } from "../../api/accounts"
import DataView from "../../app-components/DateView";

export default function AccountsPage() {
    const { data, isLoading, error } = useQuery(loadAccounts);

        return <div className="page">
        <h1>Acounts</h1>
        <DataView isLoading={isLoading} error={error}>
            <>{data.map(a => <button key={a.id}>{a.name}</button>)}</>
        </DataView>
    </div>
}
```

Here is `DataView`.

```
export default function DataView({isLoading, error, children}) {
    if (isLoading) {
        return <div>Busy</div>
    }

    if (error) {
        return <div>Error: {error}</div>
    }

    return children;
}
```

Comment: "React should not be rendering the children of DataView." Why not?

Answer (score 1):

The key here is that a tag `<DataView ...>` is just a function call with a `props` object passed as a parameter. Like any other function call in JavaScript, the parameters are evaluated before passing the value to the function. So in this case, you evaluate `data.map()` and pass **its result** to the `DataView` component as `children`. Since `data` is `undefined`, you get an error at the time of evaluation.

One solution is to pass `data` as a prop directly.

Alternatively, use conditional evaluation:

```
data && data.map(...)
```

Or the best option is to call `useQuery()` in `DataView` since that is where the values are actually used. In fact, the whole point of react hooks is to avoid passing props needlessly.

Also, you should `return <>children</>`. Otherwise you will get another error when you do have `data`.

Comment: With react-query, I'm having to add code to handle isLoading, error, and when data is empty to every component I create. It is the same exact code each time. So to try to be DRY, I created DataView as a way of reusing that code. The idea being that it shows a busy indicator or an error message when necessary and then only renders `children` when not loading and there is no error. I guess I'll just have to check if data in every component. 

To my knowledge, there is no way to pass data into `children`. Is there?